# Add a class when specific dropdown is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to reveal a link when a certain dropdown option is selected in a html5 form.

On page load I want to remove the link with id "pension-faq-icon" and only display it if the user selects `<option value="<%= User::LENDER_TYPE_PENSION_INDIVIDUAL %>" id="select-ind-pension">Individual Pension Account</option>`

Html:

```
<div class="seven columns">
                  <div class="select-holder icon icon_select">
                    <select name="user[user_subtype]" id="user_lender_type">
                      <option value="">Select type</option>
                      <option value="<%= User::LENDER_TYPE_INDIVIDUAL %>" id="select-ind">Individual Lender</option>
                      <option value="<%= User::LENDER_TYPE_PENSION_INDIVIDUAL %>" id="select-ind-pension">Individual Pension Account</option>
                      <!--<option value="sme" id="select-sme">Investment Business</option>-->
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <p class="icon icon_info form-help-pension-faq show" id="pension-faq-icon">Need help? <a href="<%= faq_pension_path %>" target="_blank">Read Our Pensions FAQ</a></p>
                </div>
```

js file:

```
var user_type = $("#user_user_type").val();
  var option_type  = $("#select").val();

if(user_type == 'lender') {
    $('#pension-faq-icon').addClass('display-none');
  }
  if (option_type == 'individual_pension_lender'){
    //$('#pension-faq-icon').removeClass('display-none');
    console.log(option_type);
  }
```

Right now the code above is successfully not displaying the line with the id "pension-faq-icon". How can I add it again if the user selects the specific dropdown option mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you need to attach a `change` event handler to the `select` which runs whenever the user selects an option. At the moment your logic only executes when the page loads.

Also note that you can simplify the process by providing a boolean to `toggle()` which specifies whether to hide or show the relevant element. Try this:

```js
$('#user_lender_type').change(function() {
  $('#pension-faq-icon').toggle($(this).val() == 'individual_pension_lender');
});
```

```css
#pension-faq-icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seven columns">
  <div class="select-holder icon icon_select">
    <select name="user[user_subtype]" id="user_lender_type">
      <option value="">Select type</option>
      <option value="lender" id="select-ind">Individual Lender</option>
      <option value="individual_pension_lender" id="select-ind-pension">Individual Pension Account</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p class="icon icon_info form-help-pension-faq show" id="pension-faq-icon">
    Need help? 
    <a href="<%= faq_pension_path %>" target="_blank">Read Our Pensions FAQ</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent dude thanks I was making that way harder than it was